# Redirect everything from domain A to domain B homepage, except redirect one specific pdf file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm using `.htaccess` to 301 redirect everything on domain A to the homepage of domain B, but I need it to ignore one specific pdf file URL on domain A, and have that domain A pdf file URL redirect to a URL on domain B.

I'm using this currently to redirect just the pdf file -

```
Redirect 301 /directory/pdffile.pdf http://domainB.com/wnewpdffile.pdf
```

But when I try to add the following rule after the pdf rule, it just redirects everything, and ignores my pdf rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domainB.com/ [R=301]
```

How can I use both rules together? Thanks

Comment: Thanks @thickguru for the edits on the code. My first time posting. I tried following the guideline of 4 spaces but it didn't seem to work. I'll go back and read the guide again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^directory/pdffile.pdf$ http://domainB.com/wnewpdffile.pdf  [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domainB.com/ [R=301]
```

Where "L" flag tells Apache not to process any more rules if this one is used.

Comment: Thanks @HPatel. but that didn't work. PDF redirect still works, but not the rest of the domain A to domain B homepage redirect.

Comment: That worked, thank you very much! I'm new on this site so I'll make sure to award answer after reading guidelines etc.